# How to make my game forcefully online to drive most of the revenue?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile

I want to know that how can I make my mobile game forcefully online so I can drive more revenue from ads and in app purchases. Please let me know and it should be a legal way.

Answer (score 0):

For ads you can use Unity Ads or Google ads.
To make achat in app I recommend this video which is very well explained https://youtu.be/F3QisbY8AQ0